# detect first script in steps of redirection with header location

Tags: javascript, php

I have interesting question. I have scripts:

```
a.php - with header("Location: b.php")

b.php - with header("Location: c.php")
```

**c.php** - here in this script I need to detect with javascript, that first script with header location sequence was a.php

Is this possible?

Comment: you can add a parameter `header("Location: b.php?caller=script_A");`

Comment: I dont understand what you are asking. Can you please clarify?

Comment: Set a cookie in `a.php` and read the cookie in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

State is not maintained in http, so you need to use some other method to track origin or history, for example sessions, cookies, or URL parameters.

A simple example using parameters:

**a.php:**

```
header("Location: b.php?origin=a.php");
```

**b.php:**

```
header("Location: c.php?origin=" . $_GET['origin']);
```

**c.php:**

```
<script>
    alert(location.search.substring(1));
</script>
```

**Edit: adding a solution using cookies**

If you don't want to use parameters, you could use cookies:

**a.php**

```
// You probably want to generate the date dynamically, it must be in the future
document.cookie = 'origin=a.php; expires=Sun, 1 Jan 2017 00:00:00 UTC; path=/'
```

**c.php**

```
// Check your origin cookie
var origin=readCookie('origin');
alert(origin);

// You probably want to remove that cookie now you've used it
document.cookie = 'origin=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC; path=/'

// Handy for reading cookies, copied from http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html
function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}
```

More info, and handy little functions for setting and getting cookies: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html

Comment: thanks. I see, without parameters from a.php and b.php, script c.php is not able to reveal this information with pure javascript (I mean without any other parameters sent).

Comment: As I described using parameters is just one option.  I've updated my answer to include a solution using cookies from JS.